# SQL - How to order by two columns

Tags: sql

Imagine we have a table 'user' with several different column. Two of them are date (date) and isValid (boolean). I would like to write sql what sort this by two columns (date and isValid). First of all i would like to sort by date ASC, then every row what has isValid = 1 should be after all row with isValid = 0. So even if have a row with date = 2022.01.01 with isValid = 0 should be before row with date 2021.01.01

Initial Data:

```
Date       IsValid
2023         0
2022         1
2025         0
2024         1
2026         0
```

Expected Data:

```
Date    IsValid
2023      0
2025      0
2026      0
2022      1
2024      1
```

Comment: You can literally order by multiple columns by default. All you have to is separate them with a comma. Did you even try googling your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a comma between the columns...

```
SELECT
    date,
    isValid
FROM
    yourTable
ORDER BY
    isValid,
    date
```

Comment: Now rows with isValid = 1 are before rows with isValid = 0. This is not what i wanted

Comment: @LiOne I find that highly unlikely, there's something you're not telling us.  Check this example; https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=6087f1ae7e671dd037d534b145bf7fa1 *(edit the example to demonstrate your issue, and add the link to your question)*.

Comment: I updated question with initial and expected result

Comment: @LiOne - Ummm, just put `isValid` first in the `ORDER BY` clause?

Comment: Yup, thanks mate

Answer (score 0):

based on your edit your ordering of column will be changed isvalid will come first then date so I changed my answer  like below

```
  order by isValid, date
```

Comment: Now rows with isValid = 1 are before rows with isValid = 0. This is not what i wanted

Comment: @LiOne share sample data and expected output

Comment: I updated, here u go

Answer (score 0):

You will need to specify desc for isValid column as it seems that you want true value records first, so your query would be like below:

```
SELECT * FROM `USER` ORDER BY `DATE`, ISVALID DESC;
```